# Regex: match anything but not "<", "{{" and "{%"

Tags: regex

I trying to implement lexer and trying to create regex what will match anything but not the following:

- <
- {{
- {%

There is that i'm trying:

```
[^(<|{{|{%)]+
```

But it also does not watch ant single "{" and "%" symbols.

It it possible to do with regex?

Input: "foo {{ bar < baz {%"
Output: "foo ", " bar ", "baz "

Comment: So suppose the text is `a {{ b`. Starting from the beginning, there's a substring `a {` that does not contain `<`, does not contain `{{`, does not contain `{%`. So by your logic that should be matched. Yet I'm pretty sure that's not what you want. (If you think I'm being overly literal, keep in mind that if you create a regex that has the exact criteria in your question, this overly literal interpretation is exactly what the computer would give it.)

Comment: Lookaheads? I need to match only "a" and "b".

Comment: I would have guessed you would want "a " and " b" for that, but yeah, either way, it's possible to do it with lookaheads. But I think the simplest approach is to do what mevdschee has answered.

Comment: That's not an option then you creating lexer (like flex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookaround based regex:

```
(?<=\s|^)(?!{[{%]|<)\S+
```

`(?!{[{%])` is negative lookahead to match any non-space text that is not `{{` or `{%`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nU2rI5/2)

Comment: Great! How to match white spaces too and not "<"?

Comment: ok can you provide some sample input and expected matches in question. That will make things more clear.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is solution. But it looks like a can not use lookaheads in lexer generated by ошыщтю So i need to find another solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are writing a templating language and you may want to split on these characters, right? If so, then you split on the positive regex: `(<|{{|{%)`

Use http://www.regexr.com/ to learn more about regexes.

Comment: I'm not splitting. I'm parsing, so i need to match anything but not this symbols.

Comment: @AntonMedvedev If you know where those markers are (and most regex engines do tell you the positions of the matches), you already have everything between them too. Look for the end position of one marker and the start of the next marker, and you have the start and end position of the text in between.

Comment: @hvd Yes, that is what I should have written :-)